# sale category to have a different color with marked down price ?

Tags: category

I have a sales category on my website .I was wondering if theres a way the sale prices which are marked down could come in special kind of color or style .

Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

You have the ability to update the look and feel of a category page in a number of ways:

- **Static blocks**. Create a new Static Block and place some HTML in it that will update the page in the desired fashion. Your Static Block can even contain style/css!
- **Custom Layout XML**. Create a new stylesheet and add it to the category by updating custom layout xml.
- **Plain-old Layout XML**. If the category ID is fixed, just add a layout handle for the category ID into the local.xml file of your theme.
- **Screw it just give me CSS**: every Magento page adds a css body class in the form of `category-[catname]`. You can target this page (provided the category name never changes haha) with plain old css rules: `.category-wedding { background-color: red; }`

Comment: hi , the category is 5 and i want that too come in bold red colour ? can you please help me with a custom code of some kind that i can enable that easily ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default Magento theme? Are you just putting the items in a "sales" category or are you actually adding a "special Price" to the products?

By default (assuming you are using the default theme), if you are using a "Special Price" on both the Category List and Product Detail pages, the regular price is crossed out, and the Special Price appears in a bold red font.

To mark a product with a special price:
In the Product Information panel on the left, select Prices.
Enter the amount of the Special Price.
Then, complete the Special Price From Date and Special Price To Date to define the period of time that the special price is in effect. You can pick the dates from the Calendar to the right of each field.
Click the Save button to save your changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the page is http://gazzbox.com/gazzydeals.html as you can see the price is crossed out but i want the price too be more bold and red in color , how do i do that ?

Comment: where exactly can i  find this in my default theme in the back end ?

Comment: I'm not sure what theme you are using, but sometimes they have these option in the backend for you to change. If your theme does not offer such thing you can always change the css.

Current CSS is:
`.special-price .price {
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #2A82D7;
}`

You'd want to change the css to something like:

`.special-price .price {
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold !important;
color: #eb0404 !important;
}`

Oppose to overwriting your theme's css I would recommend creating a custom CSS style sheet and/or custom sub-theme.

Comment: @jay do you know what theme you are using?

Comment: its either default or modern ..

Comment: how do i edit or make a new custom css ? for the exact page ?